# Excel VBA to search all formulas in a file and replace text with cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I have hundreds of formulas in a single excel file.

I want to write some `VBA` to search all formulas and replace parts of the formula with values defined in a cell with the previous value in another cell.

So for example cell `B4` contains:

```
B4 = P5 2017
```

And `B5` contains:

```
B5 = P6 2018
```

I want it to use the value to do a replace on all formulas that contain any text with the previous values from `B4` such as as:

```
[FileA P5 2017.xlsm]
```

And replace with the values from `B5`:

```
[FileA P6 2018.xlsm]
```

The naming of the files is always begins with `FileA` and ends with `.xlsm`.

I have the following `VBA` (which works) but this contains a literal value:

```
Sub FileNameUpdate()
    Cells.Replace What:="FileA P5 2018", Replacement:= _
        "FileA P6 2018", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase _
        :=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

I need it to reference the aforementioned cells but cannot get the `VBA` to work, something like this:

```
Sub FileNameUpdate()
    Cells.Replace What:="FileA $B$4", Replacement:= _
        "FileA $B$5", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase _
        :=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Also tried this:

```
Sub FileNameUpdate()
    Cells.Replace What:="FileA " & B4 & ".xlsm", Replacement:= _
        "FileA " & B5 & ".xlsm", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase _
        :=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub FileNameUpdate()
    Cells.Replace What:=Range("B4") & ".xlsm", Replacement:=Range("B5") & ".xlsm", _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                  SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```